# Getting Spam feedback on my site

Tags: html, jsp

I have a Input text box asking for email id in my website. The email is tested through regex. 
But I got feedback everyday at certain time that ignores email regex and able to store a default text in email.

for eg:
my regex formats: abcde@xyz.com
but user is able to pass a digit into email text box

Please suggest.

Comment: Where do you test the regex? in page via JS? If so can the bot see the action page that the form is submitting to and simply submit directly?

Comment: Yes.. my regex is in js page .. and user can see my action controller

Comment: maybe that's how it's getting through then. The user may not have JS enabled. You could try validating it again server side at your action page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user has JS disabled and the validation is carried out in JS then it will get ignored. If the action for the form is still valid then a user can still submit the form. You could validate the input server side when the submission is received to ensure that it is as required and bounce the user back to the initial form if it is not as desired.

Bots will often intentionally ignore any JS validation.